# Error calling a function with an associative array in Bash

Tags: bash, function, class, associative-array

I'm trying to make a kind of class in Bash using an associative array.

I have this code (in `classes.sh`):

```bash
person () {
  # Define class properties
  name=$1
  age=$2
  
  # Define class methods
  say_hello() {
    echo "Hello, my name is $name and I am $age years old."
  }
  
  # Return an array with the class methods
  declare -A class_methods=(
    ["say_hello"]=say_hello
  )
  echo "${class_methods[@]}"
}
```

Then in `main.sh`:

```bash
source "classes.sh"

# Create an instance of the class
john=$(person "John" 25)

# Call a method on the instance
${john[say_hello]}
```

Calling `${john[sayhello]}` should call the `say_hello` function, but it gives this error:

```
main.sh: line 7: say_hello: command not found
```

Can I not call functions through associative arrays, and how could I fix it?

I've tried using `echo ${john[say_hello]}`, and it works. I just think it's weird that I have to put `echo` before calling a function that has echos it already. Also, I really don't want to do it like that, because the functions I'll call later on in the project will be much more complicated.

Comment: I guess (hope) this is only for fun :). There are a couple of issues. `${john[say_hello]}` returns a string. If you want to evaluate it, you should probably use `eval`. However, function `say_hello` is not visible from where you want to call it, because it is defined inside function `person`

Comment: Why use bash for this in the first place? It'd be trivial in python but close to impossible in bash, especially if you want to consider the future maintainability of the solution.

Comment: @cornuz being defined in a function isn't the problem, it's the fact that the function is being called in a subshell so the `say_hello` that gets created isn't visible in the parent

Comment: `bash`, unlike most languages, is dynamically scoped. That means the value of `name`when you call `say_hello` is the value of `name` in whatever scope the call occurs in, not the value of `name` passed to `person`. `bash` does not have first-class functions, first-class arrays, or closures.

Comment: @tjm3772 yep. You are right.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't going to work the way you are thinking.
`person` isn't creating a scoped object each time - it's overwriting `say_hello`.
The `echo "${class_methods[@]}"` at the end is just passing back a string.

`john=$(person "John" 25)` is never going to set `$john` to anything but the string "say_hello", and running `person` with or without arguments in a subshell will only update `say_hello` in the ephemeral environment of the subshell.

```
$: person sue 3          # creates GLOBAL say_hello ewith sue & 3
say_hello

$: say_hello
Hello, my name is sue and I am 3 years old.

$: john=$(person bob 29) # assigns string, creates disposable say_hello that vanishes

$: echo ${john[@]}       # not an array
say_hello

$: echo "$john"          # just a string
say_hello

$: say_hello             # function still global with sue
Hello, my name is sue and I am 3 years old.
```

`bash` doesn't do things this way. You can construct a system that looks and feels like it, so long as you don't try to actually take advantage of the expected resulting attributes of real objects, but it's not really worth it.

`bash` is great for what it's for, but if you want things like fast floating point math, large multidimensional memory structures, or real objects with attributes and methods and *inheritance* and *encapsulation*, use `python` or `perl` or something like that.